# Difference between Bidirectional TVS diode symbols

Tags: diodes, esd, tvs, bidirectional

I am intending to use this [CDSOT23-T05C](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjuqMvjtp7JAhUmx6YKHYNVCV0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bourns.com%2Fpdfs%2FCDSOT23-T03_T36C.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG9AMIe6Xca-Wdh-dyxqjOYhvpjIw&sig2=D4wa1v_kVvn31AxoXv9VXw&bvm=bv.108194040,d.dGY&cad=rja) Bidirectional TVS diode in my design to protect two separate data lines, however the symbols in the datasheet are contradicting conventional rules.

This is how two different packages of this TVS diode family are shown in the datasheet.

[image]

and this is how I normally have seen bi/unidirectional TVS diodes

[image]

I really doubt this is a type however, I have a remote guess that I might actually need to use two of these bidirectional packages to protect two lines by ditching the 3rd foot and use 1st to connect to the data line and 2nd to the ground rather than how the **[NUP2105L](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiai-aptJ7JAhWDFaYKHfdxB7UQjhwIAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onsemi.com%2Fpub%2FCollateral%2FAND8231-D.PDF&psig=AFQjCNF31vWNzem-TFjBkdnGbrjJLx3-Qw&ust=1448088528252539)** example is shown in the second figure.

So the main question is: Can I use *a single* *CDSOT23-T05C* (bidirectional) TVS diode to protect two data lines similar to how the **NUP2105L** example is demonstrated in the second figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

The reason why you can't is because the bidirectional CDSOT23 is a single bidirectional TVS diode when pins 1 and 2 are used as the input and output of the diode(s), so you'd need two of them to be similar to a single NUP2105L.